# How do I solve this forward engineer problem on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, erd, forward-engineer

I'm trying to **forward engineer** my ERD that I made, but the Forward Engineer Process gives me as output an error. `ERROR: Error 3734: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'straatid' for constraint 'verzinzelf3' in the referenced table 'locatie'`.

But that is very odd, because the columnname *`straatid`* is in fact in the table *`Locatie`*. The relation between table *`Team`* and *`Locatie`* is exactly the same as the relation between *`Locatie`* and *`Plant`*, but it seems that I only get an **error** between the relation of table *`Locatie`* and *`Plant`*. I can't really figure out how to solve this error. Can someone maybe help me with this problem?.

This is the review of the **SQL script** that is supposed to be executed:

```sql
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;

USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`table1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table1` (
  `StraatID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Straat` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Latitude` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Longitude` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StraatID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Locatie`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Locatie` (
  `Huisnr` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `StraatID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Toevoeging` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Huisnr`, `StraatID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `StraatID_UNIQUE` (`StraatID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `Huisnr_UNIQUE` (`Huisnr` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `verzinzelf2_idx` (`StraatID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `verzinzelf2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`StraatID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`table1` (`StraatID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Team`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Team` (
  `Teamnr` INT NOT NULL,
  `StraatID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Huisnr` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `StraatID1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Teamnr`),
  INDEX `verzinzelf5_idx` (`Huisnr` ASC, `StraatID1` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `verzinzelf5`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Huisnr` , `StraatID1`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Locatie` (`Huisnr` , `StraatID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Eigenaar`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Eigenaar` (
  `Eigenaar` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Eigenaar`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Plant`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Plant` (
  `Plant beschrijving` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Kaartlokatie` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Oppervlakte` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Eigenaar` INT NOT NULL,
  `Huisnr` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `StraatID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Plant beschrijving`, `Kaartlokatie`, `Oppervlakte`),
  INDEX `verzinzelf4_idx` (`Eigenaar` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `verzinzelf3_idx` (`Huisnr` ASC, `StraatID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `verzinzelf4`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Eigenaar`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Eigenaar` (`Eigenaar`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `verzinzelf3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Huisnr` , `StraatID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Locatie` (`Huisnr` , `StraatID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Meting`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Meting` (
  `Teamnr` INT NOT NULL,
  `Plant` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Meetsoort` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Teamnr`, `Plant`),
  INDEX `verzinzelf1_idx` (`Plant` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `verzinzelf_idx` (`Teamnr` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `verzinzelf`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Teamnr`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Team` (`Teamnr`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `verzinzelf1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Plant`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Plant` (`Plant beschrijving`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

[image: And here you have a **picture** of my **ERD**]

And the full error message:

```
Executing SQL script in server

ERROR: Error 3734: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'straatid' for constraint 'verzinzelf3' in the referenced table 'locatie'
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `mydb`.`Plant`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Plant` (
          `Plant beschrijving` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `Kaartlokatie` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `Oppervlakte` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `Eigenaar` INT NOT NULL,
          `Huisnr` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `StraatID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`Plant beschrijving`, `Kaartlokatie`, `Oppervlakte`),
          INDEX `verzinzelf4_idx` (`Eigenaar` ASC) VISIBLE,
          INDEX `verzinzelf3_idx` (`Huisnr` ASC, `StraatID` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `verzinzelf4`
            FOREIGN KEY (`Eigenaar`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Eigenaar` (`Eigenaar`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `verzinzelf3`
            FOREIGN KEY (`Huisnr` , `StraatID`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Locatie` (`Huisnr` , `StraatID`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Comment: This code runs fine for me I suspect your version does not support visible indexes .What version of mysql are you on? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-indexes-tab.html

Comment: My workbench is already up-to-date. I use the 8.0